# How to make an audio stream in the Kotlin version of Android running notification and lockscreen?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-studio, web-services

> ### **all work enough for me.**
>
> ## **[ASK] How to make an audio stream player control in the Kotlin version of Android notification and lockscreen? **

#### **use function to play radio stream**

```
private fun playRadio() {

        val play_tombol: ImageButton = findViewById(R.id.tombol_play)
        play_tombol.setImageResource(R.drawable.tombol_pause)
        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer().apply {
            // Atur sumber audio stream dari URL streaming radio
            setAudioAttributes(
                        AudioAttributes.Builder().setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_MUSIC).build())
            setDataSource("https://streaming-radio.magelangkab.go.id/studio")
            prepareAsync() 
            setOnPreparedListener {
            
            it.start()

            }
        }
    }
```

#### **use function to pause audio stream**

```
fun pauseaudiostream(){

        mediaPlayer?.release()
        mediaPlayer = null
        isPlaying = true

}
```

==== ui example ====

[click to see simple project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qrL2U.png)

====== purpose =====

[Purpose 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/meJlc.jpg) | In Lockscreen (Not Yet)

[Purpose 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KO8rT.jpg) | In App ( Done )

[Purpose 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kXzqz.jpg) | In Notification (Not Yet)